# Spring JPA does not see primary foreign key in repository method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Repository:

```java
public interface CrimeCaseRepository extends JpaRepository<CrimeCase, Integer> {
    boolean existsByCrimeId(int crimeId);
}
```

CrimeCase:

```java
...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "fk_crime")
    private Integer crimeId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Crime crime;
...
```

Crime:

```java
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "crime", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CrimeCase crimeCase;
...
```

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE crime (
  id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
...
);

CREATE TABLE crime_case (
  fk_crime INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
...
);
```

Hibernate output:

> Hibernate: select cc1_0.crime_id from crime_case cc1_0 where cc1_0.crime_id=? fetch first ? rows only

Exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column cc1_0.crime_id does not exist

Exception occurs even after renaming `crimeId` to `fkCrime`. In this case it must take `id` from the `Crime` entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `@MapsId`, then both the entity should share the same primary key.
Maybe you should not be using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to begin with.

Here is a [reference](https://vladmihalcea.com/change-one-to-one-primary-key-column-jpa-hibernate/) for you

**EDIT**

How is your `crime` mapped in your database?
Why don't you explicitly use something like

```
@JoinColumn(name = "crime_id")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
private Crime crime;
```

Comment: Post is Crime alternative there. So no difference (except explicit strategy set)

Comment: Added `@JoinColumn(name = "fk_crime")`, got `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier`

Comment: Added also db details

Comment: Wait a minute, it fixed this query, but now on save it throws exception which i mentioned above. save code:         

`crimeCaseService.save(new CrimeCase(crimeId, crimeRepository.getReferenceById(crimeId))`. But I have crimeId existance check before (code i provided in question) and crimeId is not null ofc

Comment: Ok, it is an another question. Saved in one query with `crimeRepository.getReferenceById` and setting `crimeCase` of this `crime` with a new object. So after that save `crime`

Comment: * also crime should have `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` on `crimeCase`